# Odd question: How do you calculate the "value" of an area using the coordinates and a given function?

Tags: functions

So this is kind of hard to explain, but in a grid of cells, the "value" of a cell is given by the equation $$100(\sqrt[5]{d})^{-2\sqrt{10}}$$ where d is the distance from the point (0,0).

How would you calculate the total value of a rectangular area given by its coordinates (if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

Write the function as
$f(d)
=ad^b
$,
where
$a=100$
and
$b 
= -2\sqrt{10}/5
=-\sqrt{40}/5
\approx -1.2
$.

For a point at
$(i, j)$,
$d(i, j)=\sqrt{i^2+j^2}
$.

If 
$i$ goes from
$0$ to $n$
and
$j$ goes from
$0$ to $m$,
then the total is

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^m f(d(i, j))
&=\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^m f(\sqrt{i^2+j^2})\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^m a(\sqrt{i^2+j^2})^b\\
&=a\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^m (i^2+j^2)^{b/2}\\
\end{array}
$

If $b/2$ were an integer,
you could get an exact formula for this
by expanding $(i^2+j^2)^{b/2}$
with the binomial theorem.
Since it is not,
you have to leave it at this.

If you need an approximate value
for large $n$ and $m$,
you could look at this
in polar form
and approximate it by
integrating over
$r$ and $\theta$
instead of
$x$ and $y$,
but I'm not sure how to
estimate the error.